# Starting Angular2 project from nested route gives 404 while trying to load main.js

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Writing my first application in Angular2 and experimenting with Angular's Component Router (3.0.0-alpha.7) I encountered a problem that I cannot resolve.

I have defined my routes in app.routes.ts as shown in the documentation and everything seems to be working ok when loading the app from the base route (http://localhost:3000/) and routing seems to be ok.

That is until I try to reload the page from a nested route e.g. http://localhost:3000/movies/, doing so will not load the resources as the resource links are relative to the path and 404 when trying to load them.
(e.g. Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/movies/dist/main.js(…))

How can I resolve this?